# When should I use error.printStrackTrace() instead of log4.j.error()

Tags: java, logging, log4j

When should I print an error with `Throwable.printStackTrace()` instead of using the log4j methode `error(String, Throwable)`?

Where are the differences and what is the common use?

// cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Throwable.printStackTrace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29) prints your stack trace to the standard error, while log4j method will print it where do you prefer. You can specify when and how to print the stack trace via the [log4j configuration file](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html).

The second approach is the best one because you can always decide to write the error to the standard error but also to print it in a rolling file at the same time.
You have the drawback that you need the log4j dependency in your project but there are also solutions to use log4j without declaring this dependency and provide it only at runtime.

Edit: a common use is to write logs in your code using log4j api and configure log4j where you deploy your application.
Another way is to write them with java.util.logging to avoid any direct dependency and you can use [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) bridges to capture any log from your and 3rd party code and delivery it to the logging api you prefer (ie. log4j)

Answer (score 2):

Normally you wouldn't do that, since it is print the error to standard error output. If you don't persist this message(file or db), it is gone as soon as you close console.

> Prints this throwable and its backtrace to the standard error stream.

Instead, what you want is log to a file via [Logger.error(String, Throwable)](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html#error%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Throwable%29) and you can find the log file when debugging production issue. Beside that, using log4j, you can configure the log level to shows in log based on different environment, for example, in production, you might only log with level info, warning, and error levels while during development, you log debug statements as well.

> Log a message object with the ERROR level including the stack trace of
>   the Throwable t passed as parameter.

Most common use is do via logger, unless in production you don't log anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you're logging, then use Log4J method. You'll have an handle on **where and if** you want the log to be shown/read in file/console/... You can select the level of debug to show/hide certains information

Throwable.printStackTrace will only send the stack trace to the standard error stream.

Moreover with Log4J you can easily "simplify" the message and let the user/developer know whats going on.

Edit:
You may want to take a look at SLF4J which will allow you to change the Logging backend (LOG4J in your case) really easily.

Answer (score 1):

The only situations where you would use `Throwable.printStackTrace()` in preference to logging are:

- when you *can't* use logging (for some reason),
- when you *always* what the user to see the stacktrace (for some reason), or
- when you are debugging, and need a quick-and-dirty stack trace.

> Where are the differences and what is the common use?

Basically, the difference is at a higher level.  It is the difference between using a logging framework for logging, or using `System.err.println` statements for logging.

The former has a number of advantages, that you will find well described in the documentation and javadocs of various logging frameworks.  The primary ones are:

- simple fine grain control of logging; e.g. levels, categories, and so on,
- lots of options for recording and formatting log information, and
- extensive out-of-the-box configurability using config files.

Admittedly, tiny applications might not need all of this, but if your application needs to do logging at all, then using a logging framework gives you this for free with development or performance minimal overheads.